# Notepad++ 6.5 regex replace with same regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to replace a regex based on a date string with the same one and a new line. The problem is that when I write the sintax like this:

```
Replace with : (\1)\n
```

Or like this :

```
Replace with: ($1)\n
```

It only replaces it with a new line, instead of replacing it with what it finds and a new line. My regex is this:

```
(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:19\d\d|20\d\d)
```

Can you help me? Or tell me what am I doing wrong?

edit:

This is a string example of what I need:

```
03/12/2010 lots of text 05/12/2009 lots of text lots of text 13/09/2008 lots of text lots of text lots of text 23/09/2007 lots of text 20/04/2010 lots of text
```

I need it to look like this:

```
  03/12/2010 lots of text 
  05/12/2009 lots of text lots of text 
  13/09/2008 lots of text lots of text lots of text 
  23/09/2007 lots of text 
  20/04/2010 lots of text
```

Comment: It would help if you supplied a sample of what text you are using this on, and what result you want.

Comment: i made an edit on the question, with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not capturing anything with that regex, just simply matching.

In that case, you would want to put the match back, so you can use `$0` or `\0` for that:

Replace with:

```
$0\n
```

Comment: Yes, that worked fine, thank you. I used it like this: `\n$0`, to get also the date. Thanks very much:)

Comment: @RazvanN Cheers :)